# Why int64 array is so big in TimerThread

Tags: .net, multithreading, garbage-collection, windbg

I'm investigating OutOfMemoryException in 32bit process,
the following stats has drawn my attention (large int64 array):

```
!dumpheap -stat
........
707b251c        3       692500 System.Int64[]
6fa6b038    72151      2020228 System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule
6fa9b1a0    72151      2308832 System.Diagnostics.ModuleInfo
707fdd04     2404      3223807 System.Byte[]
707faea4    11990      5780152 System.Object[]
707fb37c     9847     16162530 System.Char[]
00c16a88    41026     19281740      Free
707fac04   183726     21698276 System.String
Total 758006 objects
0:000> !DumpHeap /d -mt 707b251c
 Address       MT     Size
02f5b9ec 707b251c       76     
02f7c198 707b251c       60     
03f40000 707b251c   692364     

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
707b251c        3       692500 System.Int64[]
Total 3 objects
```

```
0:000> !gcroot 03f40000
Thread 4320:
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
    1238ea6c 6fbedbd0 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc() [f:\dd\NDP\fx\src\net\System\Net\_TimerThread.cs @ 707]
        edi:  (interior)
            ->  03dc3670 System.Object[]
            ->  03f40000 System.Int64[]

Found 1 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).
```

.Net Framework 4.8 is used.
Why TimerThread needs such big array?

The dump was made out of "simplified" of app,
the initial version has more drastic figures (with more threads(229 vs 32), with app domains(~180 vs 0) loading):

```
!dumpheap -stat
..........
707b251c      387    105384412 System.Int64[]
```

Comment: `The dump was made out of "simplified" of app` - show that.

Comment: Try using a proper memory profiler to find who is actually holding all that data. Try VS profiler, or ANTS Memory Profiler.

Comment: `System.String` is more of the problem here, but you chose the least.

Comment: @LexLi that's on its way, I don't have questions there.... ))

Comment: Small update: initial app doesn't show call stack for int64[], however I suspect that it could be it 
4ef1a7d4 707b251c       76     
4f018cac 707b251c       76     
03b26f60 707b251c   583732     
03bb57a8 707b251c   587980     
03c45088 707b251c   579636

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, "simplified" doesn't mean simple. I got your point, I will try to extract the minimum/write from scratch to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it,
not sure whether TimeThread callstack that is shown by WinDbg is reflecting the reality, but
the simplest way to reproduce it is to run such Console App with main method:

```
var procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("GetProcessesByName");
     Console.ReadKey();
```

And later get the dump, which shows in my case

```
!dumpheap -stat
....
6fa595d0     7361       264996 System.Diagnostics.ThreadInfo
6fa595a4     7361       529992 
System.Diagnostics.NtProcessInfoHelper+SystemThreadInformation
7061251c        2      1003800 System.Int64[]
Total 19595 objects
```

So it seems that strange behavior is related to Process.GetProcessesByName.
However Process.GetCurrentProcess() doesn't produce any int64[] footprint in memory.

Comment: You should move this to the question itself - it's not an answer but a way to reproduce the issue. Do that, and I'll up-vote.

Comment: I see a Int64[], but not rooted at edi of ThreadProc() but at a pinned handle instead. As @500-InternalServerError said: this is not an answer and should be part of the question.